# django admin inline formset

Tags: django

Can i use inline formset in django admin, a formset based on a custom form without a model?

The ModelAdmin class has the attribute inlines allowing class inherited from TabularInline or StackedInline. But these classes need a model.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. If without a model, how can the formset objects be saved to database? As we all know that the model is the essential part of django's ORM.